# How to create an immutable NSAttributedString with a ranged attribute

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring, nsrange

How can I initialize an `NSAttributedString` with a ranged attribute?

As it stands, I can only work out how to add a ranged attribute after initialization, which obviously doesn't work for immutable `NSAttributedString` instances.

If I have an `NSMutableAttributedString`, I can call:

```
[str addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName value:url range:range];
```

If I have an `NSAttributedString`, I can construct it:

```
[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:str attributes:@{NSLinkAttributeName: url}];
```

But I can't find a way to put a range into the attributesDict.

Thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Start with an NSMutableAttributedString. If that isn't what you have, make a mutable copy by calling `mutableCopy` on an NSAttributedString. Now you *do* have an NSMutableAttributedString.

So now do whatever you need to do.

When you are finished, if you really need an NSAttributedString, call `copy` on the NSMutableAttributedString to get an immutable copy. (But it is hard to see why you would need to do this, because you can always pass an NSMutableAttributedString where an NSAttributedString is expected.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this line of code.

```
NSString *name = @"firstname lastname";
NSAttributedString *username = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:name];

NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:username];
[mutableAttributedString addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName value:@"www.yourdomain.com" range:NSMakeRange(0, name.length)];
```

Furthermore, you can another line ot text after your range

```
[mutableAttributedString appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"other description"]];
```

**Output**

[firstname lastname](http://www.yourdomain.com/) other description